# Windows file backup software

Tags: windows, backup

I'm looking for the backup software for Windows servers aswell as for the workstations.

We always used Acronis but backup&recovery 10 is slow as hell and has too many bells and whistles (i.e. their new metainfo) so I would be really happy to throw it away.

The software requirements:

- should work on win7 aswell as on win server 2008 r2
- should be simple and fast, we are backing up only the individual files, no partition backups, but it would be nice to store only a changed parts of the large files instead of storing changed files fully when doing incrementals
- backing up the open/busy files is required. also on the encrypted (truecrypt/bestcrypt) drives, where windows volume shadow copy doesn't work.
- no any complex backup metadata, if I remove all backups from the backup folder, it should automatically understand the full backup is required, then do an incrementals until I clear/rotate the backup folder again. I would like to control backup rotation manually instead of using any complex rotation and consolidation systems.
- backup encryption (including the filenames) - aes256+password.
- tape support is nice but not required. We do backups only to the network and local drives.
- mounting backups as a drives is nice but also not necessary.

So something like Acronis TrueImage 9 or before. More simple - much better. Client/server is not required.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at Cobian backup.  It uses volume shadow copy and seems to be very reliable from my experience.

Comment: No advanced file field/block level delta/SIS features, but very straight forward.

Comment: unfortunately it even can't stable do an incremental backups.

Comment: Really!? Never experienced it having any problems with incremenatals, as that is the way we usually set it up.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Amanda](http://www.amanda.org/). Best of all it's open-source, and if you want to have it supported, you can go up to the commercial [zmanda](http://www.zmanda.com/)

Comment: As far as I know, Amanda/Bacula have a client/server architecture, aren't they? Too complex for our tasks I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the Windows backup features with Windows 2008R2? There has been significant changes from the old NT Backup, a lot of it may actually meet your identified requirements.

Comment: sorry, forgot to notify in my question - the software should be able to work with bestcrypt/truecrypt encrypted drives, Windows backup can't.